# Drop constraints only if it exists in mysql server 5.0

Tags: mysql4

i want to know how to drop a constraint only if it exists. is there any single line statement present in mysql server which will allow me to do this.

i have tried the following command but unable to get the desire output

```
alter table airlines 
drop foreign key if exits FK_airlines;
```

any help to this really help me to go forward in mysql

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe this is possible in a single line, unless you are **willing** to detect the error and move on (not a bad thing).

The INFORMATION_SCHEMA database contains the info you need to tell if the foreign key exists, so you could implement it in a 2 step process.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/table-constraints-table.html

Comment: I'm willing to 'detect the error and move on' OR to use a '2 step process', but unfortunately the link you offer is not enough to get me there - could you elaborate please?

Answer (score 0):

yep not possible the if exist is available only for database table and view :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-features-drop-if-exists.html

yep 2 step process is a good way like gahooa said