# MySQL drop foreign key constraint only if it exists

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Been looking for almost an hour now, and i can't believe i haven't figured out how to do this yet.  I've found this:

[Drop constraints only if it exists in mysql server 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544825/drop-constraints-only-if-it-exists-in-mysql-server-5-0)

but the link offered there is not enough info to get me there.. Can someone offer an example with code, please?

**UPDATE**

Sorry i wasn't clear in the original question, but i was hoping for a way to do this in just SQL, not utilizing any application programming.

Answer (score 2):

example php code:

```
function removeFK(PDO $pdo, $dbName, fkName)
{
    echo "Removing foreign key '$fkName' from database: $dbName\t";

    $exists = $pdo->query("
        SELECT TRUE
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
        WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'
            AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '$dbName'
            AND CONSTRAINT_NAME = '$fkName'
        ")->fetchColumn();

    if ($exists === false) {
        echo " [SKIPPING] (FK does not exist)\n";
        return false;
    }

    $pdo->query("USE $dbName");
    $pdo->query("
        ALTER TABLE intelligence_webpage_has_region_keyword
        DROP FOREIGN KEY $fkName");

    echo "[OK]\n";
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate this, makes sense and looks like it would work.  But i was hoping for a pure SQL solution; updated the question.

Comment: A pure MySql solution is required.